# 100+ bluetooth devices in close proximity? Will there be issues?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm evaluating the use of over 100 Bluetooth headsets in a call center environment.

My understanding of Bluetooth.. is that the stream of data is chopped up over 79 bands. So a telephone call can exist over those 79 bands (one at a time) in any given instance.

What I don't get is what will happen if 80 bluetooth devices were transceiving in a close proximity? Can you have two streams over a single radio band? what will the 80th stream of data do?

Cant find a clear answer online so would appreciate help!

**edit:** Kruug asking which band I was in set me in the right direction - turns out there's more space in 6-9GHz :)

thanks!

Comment: Are the devices/receivers on the 2.4 GHz band or the 6-9 GHz band?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you will hear multiple people talking on one line. For example you have 2 sets of 2 people talking on phone, 1 person from each set are using bluetooth, they walk by each other and for some reason suddenly there is a 4-way conversation going on.

I know this from past experience, which is why I don't use bluetooth anymore, it is highly susceptible to signal jacking.